# Can Admob Banner ad and Interstitial Ad be implemented on the same activity?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, banner, interstitial

I'm new to android. I'm building an app for playing and downloading audio from firebase.
So far my app is working fine, but i want to know if my ads placements in the app are okay or not.

In my activity i have two buttons, one for playing and another button for downloading.

I dont want to disturb a user with interstitial ads when he's/she's playing and listening music, and thus, only banner ad placed on the bottom of the activity_layout will be shown the whole time music is playing.

I also placed an interstitial ad which will be shown only a few seconds after a user press a download button.

So far, Both of my ads are working fine. I want to know if this is okay or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both Ads in the same activity, go a head with your approach.